# Background color not set for Spinner elements

Tags: android, spinner

I have this static method to colorize the background of Spinner entries, but it is not working. Any idea on why? How would you do this without extending `SpinnerAdapter`?

```
public static void colorizeSpinnerElements(final Activity activity, final int id) {
    final Spinner aux = (Spinner) activity.findViewById(id);
    final SpinnerAdapter adapter = aux.getAdapter();
    if (adapter != null) {
        final int num = adapter.getCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            adapter.getView(i, null, null).setBackgroundColor(ColorHelper.COLOR_LIST[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I think it might be related to the fact that I only do this when loading the `Spinner`, and so it loses the background color when `getView()` is called to refresh display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do the same from the **adapter's getView()** method :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    v.setBackgroundColor(ColorHelper.COLOR_LIST[position]);
    return v;    
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can `override` the `getDropDownView` method. This method is called for each item.

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

   if (view == null) {
       LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       // expand your list item here
       view = vi.inflate(R.layout.mylistitem, null);
    }
    // get whatever items are in your view
    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    ImageView left = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.leftImage);

    // do whatever you want with your item view 

    view.setBackgroundColor(ColorHelper.COLOR_LIST[position]);    
    return(view);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but *"How would you do this without extending SpinnerAdapter?"* :)

Comment: I finally had to use a `ListView`. Anyway, thanks for your help! :)